# Creating readable polls with many time slots (Doodle-like)

Tags: scheduling, communication, planning

#### What I would like to achieve

I am organizing a meeting with people from different institutions and companies, and I would like to use an online polling tool, like Doodle, to let them choose dates and times.

I would like them to choose a day and a time in a range of 5 days, where they can also choose any 1-hour time slot from 8am to 8pm.

#### Issues

The problem is that, using Doodle, if there are ***many time slots*** then the online poll page is quite unreadable to read, as each participant must must look at a lot of options (see the two pictures at the bottom, especially the "week mode" page which looks horrible).

#### Possible solution

I think that the only way to avoid this is to only show the days plus **just a range** for time (e.g. from 8am to 8pm) and the participants, when they choose a day, should also be able to add the time slots (or sub-ranges) by themselves, or they can choose a time slot previously added by another participant.

#### Then I ask:

Do you think there is a way to achieve this using, for example, the Doodle online platform? Otherwise, do you know any other Doodle-like method or tool/website where the above-mentioned feature would be available?

### Examples

**Doodle calendar mode**

[image]

**Doodle week mode (this is really bad)**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried http://whenisgood.net ?

Comment: That is a very good suggestion, as the page with all choices is so much lighter and does not need scrolling! I would be very happy to see this suggestion as an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://whenisgood.net is an online scheduler program similar to Doodle with a streamlined interface. You can click on a timeslot to indicate it's free, or click and hold to indicate a range of timeslots.

Plus, even if the page still shows all the time slots, this is not confusing anymore as it does not need scrolling, everything just fits in a small space, as shown below.

#### Example

[image]

Comment: I added a picture to your answer to also show that time slots are much more readable than in Doodle without the need of scrolling, what do you think?